# Does replacing an assembly in the GAC cause a reset?

Tags: 2007, wspbuilder, deployment, gac

So, I have a web part I wrote that is not working correctly, I get "object reference not set to an instance of an object." it works fine in dev, but when I installed in prod, it doesn't.

Anyway, if I replace the assembly in the GAC, does that cause any kind of iis reset, or app pools to recycle? Or do I need to reset anything for it to pick up the new assembly?

I only ask because I will not be allow to reset anything on the SP server during business hours, so I don't want to copy the new assembly if it will reset anything. In dev, I deploy using WSPBuilder, and I think that recycles the app pools when I click "Copy to GAC".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yea, you'll need to do an iisreset or an app pool recycle for it to pick up the new dll in the gac.

Comment: when you do an iisreset you should include /noforce parameter to prevent services from being forced to restart if they cannot do so gracefully

Answer (score 1):

If you got RDP access to the server, I'd do it this way.

1. Open the C:\Windows\assembly folder
2. Open the folder where your dll is located
3. Copy the dll to the assembly folder
4. Wait untill you can reset the webserver
5. Do an iisreset /noforce or recycle the application pools via IIS Manager

If you don't have (RDP) access to the server you could write a script (or use the ones from WSP Builder). Just be carefull. I think the default scripts of WSP Builder cause a reset automatically. You'll have to edit those manually.